# Can I merge two views into a third one

Tags: views

I'm new to views and was wondering how I can accomplish this:

I have two views one that takes receivable invoices and displays them and then totals them at the end of the table using View Aggregate Plus. Another view that grabs invoices that are payable and once again totals these together.

What I'm looking for is a way to take the total of these two views and then display it in a third view called balance which will take the total of receivable invoices and subtract the total of payable invoices.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It might be nice if I could get an answer instead of just someone saying you have done this already. Since I didn't get an answer the first time, I simply thought I reword it and see if that helps.

Comment: There's no easy way to explain it. I need to take the results of two different views and place them in a third view

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions. If you can edit the original to make it clearer please do so, but there's no need to have two copies of the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to render multiple views on a single template file.

you need to make use of [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)
Using this function, you can embed Views and even dynamically pass them filter arguments. - See more at: http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-embed-view-template-tpl

you can use this function multiple time to get your both views rendered and then do your operations on variables available from them [you need to figure out this at-least], here is the [help](https://api.drupal.org/comment/33023#comment-33023)